# What is the correct content-type header for Json RPC v2 over HTTP?

Tags: json, http, http-headers, content-type, json-rpc

I know that JSON RPC is not directly specified with HTTP, but I cannot find a proper solution for this. The question is, which `content-type` is correct:

1. `content-type: application/json`
2. `content-type: application/json-rpc`
3. both?

In the [official (?) doc for v2](http://www.jsonrpc.org/specification) and [v1](http://json-rpc.org/wiki/specification) there is nothing about content-types only in [this seemingly deprecated document](http://www.jsonrpc.org/historical/json-rpc-over-http.html) about JSON rcp v1.2 there is the definition of (2) but optional (1).

By investigating the popular [jsonRPC4J java lib](https://github.com/briandilley/jsonrpc4j) that uses v2 spec I found in the client that they set (2):

```
    /**
     * Prepares a connection to the server.
     * @param extraHeaders extra headers to add to the request
     * @return the unopened connection
     * @throws IOException 
     */
    protected HttpURLConnection prepareConnection(Map<String, String> extraHeaders)
        throws IOException {

        ...
        con.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json-rpc");

        // return it
        return con;
    }
```

For me best practice would be to just accept both to be on the "safe" side?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After a quick google search I see others using `application/json` which is what I would have expected for JSON.  Since the documentation doesn't specify, I imagine this could be hit or miss depending on the implementation of the server.

Maybe you could implement a routine that tried the other on a bad response?  Not ideal, but the docs aren't helping you much.